# What does the word "Neela(नील)" actually mean in the vedas

Tags: vedas

The Shatarudriya mentions Rudra as Nīlagrīva , some translators translate this is "black necked" , so what is the actual meaning of the word "Nīla(नील)" mean in the Vedas?

Answer (score 0):

Nīla(नील) means blue in whichever context you Interpret it.

[Here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/essay/rudra-shiva-concept-study/d/doc1146720.html#note-t-204959):

> Rudra is called Nīlagrīva. Uvaṭa illustrates this term as the sun when
> it is rising and setting, at that time it appears blue-necked

Another Interpretation:

> That means Nīlagrīva is depicted as one whose neck is blue in colour
> for holding poison in his neck. According to Sāyaṇācārya, Rudra is
> blue-necked for bearing kālakūṭa in his neck

More definitions can be found [here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/nilagriva).

Comment: Thanks!but why do some scholars interpret the word as "Black" and even in the Chāndogya Upanishad 1.6.5 , Nīla(नील) is equated with Black(कृष्ण वर्ण)?

Comment: I don't think it is pure black. It could mean "dark" though. In Tamil, Krishna is often referred to as "karu neela kannan" which means Dark Blue Krishna. "Karu" means dark and "Karuppu" means black.

Comment: Thanks , the possibility of Nīla meaning black is less as the word Krishna is already used in the Rigveda to denote black